# what do RC4 and RC5 mean in relation to angular2

Tags: angular, module

I'm new to angular and am confused at what people mean when converting between RC4 and RC5 and what the difference is exactly.

All the online posts just talk about how to convert from one to the other as opposed to what they are?

Comment: See Gunter's answer. Basically since Angular 2 is still in pre-release those are the candidates for a final build. See https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Software_release_life_cycle#Release_candidate

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's just a version number.

Release candidate 4
Release candidate 5

It's not known how many RC there will be before final release.

- https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
- https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/rc4-to-rc5.html